# Authenticate with spotify on express server and iOS client

Tags: ios, express, spotify

Here is my current authentication flow for a web client using https://github.com/JMPerez/passport-spotify on an express server.

passport spotify auth flow:

[image]

However, I am building the server for an iOS client. Here is how i want the auth flow to look:

[image]

The reason I want the second auth flow is that the client will be making calls to the Spotify Web API. However, I want my expressjs app to authenticate with Spotify too because I want to retrieve the user's Spotify profile and store it in my database.

Would it be ok to use the second auth flow? Or am I better off having the server authenticate with Spotify, and send then send the tokens back to the client for further requests

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of preference. Both ways will accomplish what you want. I like to have my server do it most of the time because then I don't have to duplicate the auth code on the client and server